# Portal authorization to other portal's Dashboard

Tags: php, web-services, api, authorization

There is a portal that a company's users are familiar with, and we will put a link to login to a different portal on a different machine. This process would not require username/password check, just hitting the link will log them in.

How can this two delivered in secured way? We don't want that anyone with the link to be able to log in, how can we make this to work between the two platforms?

Comment: So, user has already logged in, inside main site. You want that login information carry on, onto another site server, when its clicked, so new server will know, that this is authorised user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming the two portals aren't able to share sessions/cookies.  If they are you can just use those to keep track of who is logged in where.

In the situation where that's not possible, you could use an authentication API, which you could query to see if a given user_id is logged in on that portal.  This could be a very simple API which returns a yes or no, or you could develop it to be more complex.

Additionally keep in mind that there are Open Source choices out there.  Open ID is a system that stackoverflow uses, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest method would be script on main site, that waits for session ID in POST/GET input, if session exists, it outputs user name. The new site server, when user comes in, reads in cookie with session ID, sends a request to main site server script and asks if session ID exists, if exists, uses that user name, for new site server.